# Pandas compare function display 1st column

Tags: python, compare

Need to compare 2 dataframes containing 250k records. Both the dataframes have 1st column as primary key 'PK'
I'm applying compare function to these dataframes and getting some 7 records in common.

Now, due to compare function am getting correct no. of similar records but I need primary key also to be printed in order to locate the record. The index number is getting printed but not the primary key name.

Is there a way to print the "PK" column within compare report?

```
newDF = df1.compare(df2, keep_equal=True, result_names=('DEV1','DEV2')
```

Actual result:

```
           AMOUNT_DAILY_BAL
          DEV1     DEV2
160102     101     122
160375     211     233
160455     231     245.0
160567     765.9    343
170333     323     112
170756     399     402
170888     343     565
```

Expected result:

```
           AMOUNT_DAILY_BAL
         PK    DEV1     DEV2
160102   ASD1  101     122
160375   QWE4  211     233
160455   WSX2  231     245.0
160567   ZXS2  765.9    343
170333   WWW1  323     112
170756   ABC3  399     402
170888   OPU9  343     565
```

The index is very well present in the dataframes DF1 and DF2. But how to get this inserted in the compare report format? I cannot switch the format now and I need this PK value anyhow.

Comment: Can you please provide some sample data leading to such result?

Comment: Please use universal measurements and try to avoid using local words like *lakh* that not everyone understands.

Answer (score 0):

The pandas.DataFrame.compare() function is used to compare two dataframes and display the differences between them. By default, the function displays the differences in all columns of the two dataframes.

If you want to only display the differences in the first column, you can pass a specific column name to the compare() function. For example:

```
import pandas as pd
```

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3], 'B': ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 4, 3], 'B': ['foo', 'bar', 'qux']})

diff = df1.compare(df2, subset=['A'])

print(diff)
This code will compare the two dataframes df1 and df2 and only display the differences in the column 'A'. The subset parameter is used to specify which columns to compare, and in this case, we're only comparing the 'A' column.

If you want to display the differences in multiple columns, you can pass a list of column names to the subset parameter. For example:
diff = df1.compare(df2, subset=['A', 'B'])
This code will compare the two dataframes df1 and df2 and display the differences in both the 'A' and 'B' columns.

Comment: The primary key column in my case is same in both the dataframes.
I need to capture this value in order to locate the record in which a change is observed for any column.
So need is to show the difference I'm all records but need to print the 'PK' column always, irrespective there exists any difference or not.
If all Cell values are same for a record the need not print this column value. But only when there appears a cell to Cell comparison difference then need this PK value to be printed in order to locate the record.